# Get multiple users from people picker in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I tried getting usernames out of People picker (multi users) in Display form.

I tried `getFieldValue()` from  `spjs-utility`. It shows null/empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       var getIDPeoplePicker=$("div[Title='Column Name of the people picker here']").id;
        var ppobject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict [getIDPeoplePicker];
     var usersobject = ppobject.GetAllUserInfo();
    usersobject.forEach(function (index) {
      usersobject[index].DisplayText;
       usersobject[index].EntityData.Email;
         });
```